# How to declare the list type in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I found all [Type Specifiers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/04_bc.htm) of common lisp. There is the `list` inside. But there is no example of declare `list` in Common Lisp like array has, `(declare (array fixnum 10))`.

So, what's the right way to declare a list type specifier? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `LIST` type specifier doesn't have a built-in way to specify the types of the list elements. It's just short for `(OR CONS NULL)`.

You can use `DEFTYPE` to define a type specifier that specifies the element types using `SATISFIES`, as shown in the [Type System](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/type.html#declaring-the-type-of-variables) page of T*he Common Lisp Cookbook*.

```
(defun list-of-strings-p (list)
  "Return t if LIST is non nil and contains only strings."
  (and (consp list)
       (every #'stringp list)))

(deftype list-of-strings ()
  `(and list (satisfies list-of-strings-p)))
```